# How to convert JSON object with xy coordinates to image in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I am having a JSON object with xy coordinates. My required output is an image(PNG or JPG). How to convert this JSON to image PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: You should convert your json in Array and then fill an image with the color affrected of each pixel represented with xy coordinates using something like imagesetpixel (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php )

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us so that we are able to help! You can edit your question with the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), details of the exact problem you are having with the code, and what you have already tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ImageMagick function `importImagePixels`.

First convert your JSON data to an array. Then use `importImagePixels` as below.

```
$image->importImagePixels(0, 0, $width, $height, "RGB", Imagick::PIXEL_CHAR, $pixelArray);
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
$image->writeImage("image.jpg");
```